# Why does line-height add extra height?

Tags: html, css, iframe

```
<div><iframe style="height: 100px"></iframe></div>
<div style="line-height: 0"><iframe style="height: 100px"></iframe></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6SD4/

If you inspect the DOM you can see that the first div has a height of 108px while it's 104px on the second one. The iframe with borders is 104px so why is it adding 4 extra pixels when line-height is set?

Tested on Chrome 28.0.1500.71 for Mac.

Comment: it is actually adding 4 pixels when line-height is NOT set... in you're question you've mistyped (you said first div is bigger then second but adds pixels?

Comment: @Qreatives I set it to 0 in the second div. It's "line-height: normal;" in the first one.

Comment: Thanks @Adrift. That's probably what I wanted, yes. Not sure why it works though.

Comment: ah ok yeah my bad, i misinterpreted your "set"/"not set".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the iframes sit on the baseline. But the div has to be tall enough to contain the [strut](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#strut) as well, which drops below the baseline, and whose height is determined by the line-height.

0 line-height = 0px strut height = 0px of the strut below the baseline.

Use `iframe { display:block; }` or `iframe { vertical-align:top; }` or `iframe { vertical-align:bottom; }`  to stop this happening.

(display:block stops the line box from being created, so there is no strut. vertical-align:top and vertical-align:bottom free the strut from sharing the line box's baseline with the iframe, so the strut get placed higher such that no part of it is below the bottom of the iframe. Note that if the line-height is greater than the iframe height, the strut will force the line-box height and thus the div height to still be greater than the iframe height, regardless of the vertical-align setting)

Answer (score 2):

Both divs seem to be 109px tall in Chrome 28. Keep in mind that the default `vertical-align` value for an `<iframe>` element and all inline elements is baseline - changing this to bottom will align both elements like you probably expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/p6SD4/1/

Answer (score 0):

That might depend on your browser. With Firefox and Chrome both IFRAME elements have a height of 104px (100px + 4px of border).

What browser are you using ? Have you tried with border="0" ?

Comment: Using Chrome 28.0.1500.71 for Mac. Removing the border doesn't make any differences. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Sadly not the first time I've seen discrepancies between Chrome for Mac and Chrome for PC. As if different browsers weren't enough...